# Arbitrary arrays handling F#

Tags: types, f#

I'm trying to make a module in F# where i need to have some types consisting of array's of some arbirary type and with som arbitrary length.

to come with an example lets say i need to make a module for arbitrary large vector calculations.

then my idea is

```
module Vector =
type Vector = V of array<_>
let (+) (v1:Vector) (v2:Vector) = Vector.map2 (+) V1 V2
```

but this is not working because the map2 function are not declaret for vectors yet and that's is the question, How do I declare the map2 function for an new type with the same proberties ad an array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `map2` already exists for arrays, so you can reuse it.

But please note that if you use a let-bound function for `(+)` it will be accesible only inside the type, so you should use a static member instead.

Then to call the existing `map2` function you can use pattern matching to de-compose your Single-Case Discriminated-Union:

```
type Vector<'t> = V of array<'t> with
    static member (+) (V v1, V v2) = V (Array.map2 (+) v1 v2)
```

But if you still want to create the `map2` function for your type, in order to use it in a more generic way you can create it like this:

```
type Vector<'t> = V of array<'t> with
    static member map2  f (V v1) (V v2) = V (Array.map2 f v1 v2)
    static member (+) (v1, v2) = Vector<_>.map2 (+) v1 v2
```

Comment: I got another question about handling arbitrary arrays. I wish to creat another type which has the type "array of arrays"

I testet array2D and find that it was alot slower to work with. (sequences of sequences) I have to have the property that alle inner arrays are the same length but that i think i can handle on my own. But i can't find the arbitrary way to denote a array of arrays when declaring a type.

i tried something like

type Matrix = M of array<array<_>>

Comment: sry for the comment above

I got another question about handling arbitrary arrays. I wish to creat another type which has the type "array of arrays" I testet array2D and find that it was alot slower to work with. (sequences of sequences)  But I can't find the arbitrary way to denote a array of arrays when declaring a type. 

I tried something like

type Matrix = M of array<array<_>> 

or

type Matrix<'a,'b> = M of array<'a,'b> (or <'a><'b>)

but it allways turns back a single dimensional array.

Comment: @kam I think is better for you and the community if you post your questions individually. You'll get more visibility so other people can answer as well who might have a better solution than me.